# Weblogic's Ear shared properties file

Tags: java, maven, properties, weblogic

I got an Ear with a war inside, deployed in Weblogic 12c.
The project is a Maven multi-module project.

I'm trying to find a very simple way to accomplish my boss's request to put an unique properties file inside the ear (let's say in src\main\application\config), and access it by any module project.

No file within domain server (so the file got to be located in the ear) and no command input lines are allowed.

I've tried to read how to weblogic handles custom global property file here:

[External properties file with Weblogic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6664021/external-properties-file-with-weblogic)

...hey what is this mess? Seriously...everything in weblogic got to be so complicated?

Maybe with a maven plugin am I able to copy during build the property file inside any "src\main\resources" folder of the other sub-modules?

Any idea is appreciated...

thanks!

Comment: I would suggest to take a look into the [documentation of the maven-ear-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/usage.html) which shows that you can put files like this into `src/main/application`. But a shared property files does not make sense there. Better would be to make a single jar file which contains that property...