# Not able to load external properties files with springboot in weblogic

Tags: spring-boot, weblogic

I am trying to load the external properties file in spring boot with tomcat it is working as expected while putting it in lib folder but I am not able to load with weblogic server though I put application.properties file in lib folder.

Code snippet :

```
     public class ApplicationFilesInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

       @Override
       protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {

          return application.sources(Application.class).properties(getProperties());
       }

       static Properties getProperties() {
          Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("spring.config.location","classpath:{appname}-application.properties");
         return props;
       }

    }
```

Comment: Hard to tell without more detail. Did you write the code that read the external properties file? Can you show it?

Comment: @StephaneNicoll : I have added code.

Comment: so you put a file named"appname-application.properties" in the lib directory and you expect weblogic to see it? If I got that right, that's probably some feature of Tomcat but you should not rely on that. Make sure that this file is actually on the classpath of the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So Below is the link to load external properties file.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

The code which you share will work in tomcat as under lib folder is the actual classpath so it will load while server start up, but it will not work with weblogic as weblogic classpath is user domain folder and not the lib folder.

Can you try to put application.properties file in user domain folder and it should work.

Find your user domain path in weblogic and put app. files there.

Below is the code you can find your weblogic user domain path/classpath :

```
 String appDomianPath= System.getProperty("user.dir"); 
 System.out.println(appDomianPath);
```

Comment: @Boot : How can I find the weblogic server classpath?

Comment: I have edited in the answer. I also agree with @Stephane that you should not expect same behavior like tomcat in weblogic.Thumb rule is your files should be in your classpath.

Comment: It is working fine after putting app.prop file in my classpath (which is one level above lib folder). Thanks @S Boot and  StephaneNicoll for clearing my concept and for quick help.