# Accesing spring boot's application.properties on weblogic 10.3.6

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, weblogic

I am trying to acces a value defined in application.properties in a following way:

```
@Value("${server.url}")
private String serverUrl;
```

It works on embedded tomcat, but when I upload it to Weblogic I get the following error:

> Error creating bean with name 'authorizationServiceImpl': Injection of
>   autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder
>   'server.url' in value "${server.url}"; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder
>   'server.url' in value "${server.url}"

How can I make use of the application.properties file when hosting app on Weblogic server?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using external properties files in weblogic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1245955/using-external-properties-files-in-weblogic)

Comment: put what in application properties? the value of server.url is in that file. The application itself has to be run as a .war on weblogic server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that if you want to use external properties on weblogic 10.3.6 you need to put the file in desired location and use the follwing annotation for setting property source in configuration/startup class:

```
@PropertySource(value = { "file:/...domains/MYdomain/application.properties" })
```

Answer (score 0):

You should never place the application-XXX.properties files specific to an environment in the deployed component itself.

You should always externalize them outside it.

So, to solve your missing properties file problem, you have just to add the properties file(s) in a folder that you will add in the weblogic runtime classpath.

You can set the `setDomainEnv.cmd/sh` file of your domain and
add the folder path in the CLASSPATH variable.

For example, in Weblogic (11, 12 and maybe other older versions but not sure), in  `setDomainEnv.cmd`, you should find this lines :

```
set JAVA_OPTIONS=%JAVA_OPTIONS%

@REM SET THE CLASSPATH
```

Replace     `@REM SET THE CLASSPATH` by

```
SET CLASSPATH = %CLASSPATH%;yourPropertiesFilesAbsolutePath
```