# Set system property for weblogic application

Tags: java, spring, weblogic

I am running a Java Spring application on weblogic server. This application uses a config property which is not defined in code but should be passed as an argument. Value for this property should be passed as Argument when the application starts.

But the application has to run on weblogic server. How can the property be set for the application while running on weblogic server?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I think [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43975472/accesing-spring-boots-application-properties-on-weblogic-10-3-6) can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass your config property as part of JVM property

```
 -DMyArg=MyValue
```

and in your code write following code to access the value

```
 value=System.getproperty("MyArg");
```

Comment: Yes, adding -D argument in startWeblogic.cmd files java vm solved the problem. Thanks Ravi

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have set the system property correctly in Weblogic then you can use the Spring `@Value` annotation:

```
public class SomeClass{

    @Value("${some.property.name}")
    public String someProperty;

}
```

Properties can be resolved form various places, including system properties.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html